# Where does netfilter-persistent save the iptables rules?

Tags: iptables

Been looking where does netfilter-persistent store its rules but could not find any documentation about it on help.ubuntu.com.

Does anybody know where does netfilter-persistent in Ubuntu save its rules so it survives a reboot?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found it only works if you install 'iptables-persistent' package as well.

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent netfilter-persistent
```

It will be saved in **/etc/iptables/rules.v[4-6]**

If you only install netfilter-persistent, it wont save any configuration

Comment: oh, that's why! Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: Actually, just `sudo apt install iptables-persistent` is enough. It will install `netfilter-persistent` as dependency automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Ignivs' answer is perfect. However, I want to complement it a little.

In `man netfilter-persistent`, it says "All plugins are stored in /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d". Part of `/usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables` reads

```
save_rules()
{
    if [ ! "${IPTABLES_SKIP_SAVE}x" = "yesx" ]; then
        touch /etc/iptables/rules.v4
        chmod 0640 /etc/iptables/rules.v4
        iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
    fi
}
```

Then we know that the rules are actually saved by `iptables-save` and stored in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`.