# Run a Bash script to set up iptables at startup

Tags: networking, bash, scripts, cron, iptables

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 Server.

I want to use a Bash script for iptables at startup, but I dont wanna use crontab or init.d. Is there any possible way to achieve this without them?

```
#!/bin/bash
IPT="/sbin/iptables"
$IPT --flush
$IPT --delete-chain
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT*
```

Comment: Isn't that what `netfilter-persistent` is for? see for example [Where does netfilter-persistent save the iptables rules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911863/where-does-netfilter-persistent-save-the-iptables-rules)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to install additional software, one possible workaround that works on Ubuntu 16.04 is to create two scripts one which will save the Iptables current configuration and one which will restore it. These scripts must be placed in (or sim-linked to) `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/` and `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/`. Also must be executable files and must not have any extensions, like *.sh*. Here is how these scripts look on my system:

```bsh
$ cat /etc/network/if-post-down.d/iptables-save
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables-save > /root/iptables-current-state.dat
exit 0

$ cat /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables-restore
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables-restore < /root/iptables-current-state.dat
exit 0
```

Comment: Just to also note that you will need ifup and ifdown installed for this to work. Sometimes these are not installed by default (at least on rackspace ubuntu 18)

Answer (score 0):

On my 16.04 servers I use the `/etc/network/interfaces` file method:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces file for smythies.com 2016.01.30
#       attempt to set local DNS herein, as the method
#       used with the old 12.04 server no longer works.
#
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
pre-up /home/doug/init/doug_firewall
dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1

# The primary interface (d-link PCI card)
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp

# Local network interface (uses built in ethernet port)
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
  address 192.168.111.1
  network 192.168.111.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.111.255
```

Where you see I use a `pre-up` directive in the local interface definition to execute my (mainly) iptables script.

NOTE: this method will not work with later releases that use netplan instead of ifup ifdown.

Comment: Thats one good alternative @Doug Smythies, thanks for sharing it, i will install netplan and test it.

Comment: @DonJohnny : No, don't install netplan. It will make this method NOT work. Netplan is the reason I have not migrated from 16.04 to 18.04 for my servers.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the startup script to Ubuntu startup applications. There are detailed instructions here (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en). Remember you make your script executable before you add it to the startup applications.

Comment: i dont see any detailed instructions :D Btw i am using Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

Comment: I didnt know you were using the Server edition, you can use https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux

Comment: Tried out arleady with systemd, but i didnt achieve my goals. Thanks for the anwser

Comment: What went wrong @DonJohnny?

Comment: The Startup Applications mechanism is for invoking applications when a user logs in to their desktop session - I don't think it's appropriate for something at the system level such as iptables

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for advice :) George Udosen. Nothing went wrong everything was fine, i just wanna to have the script booting outside the daemons.